# Can a WebSetup contain multiple web applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to configure a websetup for the first time for our ASP.NET application which consists of 11 web services.  Is it possible to create an msi that will install the app and the 11 web services and also set-up the app pools & create the apps in IIS?  Or would I need an individual setup for each web service?  Basically I need to make it as simple as possible for the client to release.  Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have each web service in its own project?

Comment: Yes each web service is in a seperate project

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can because the setup wont allow you to pick different root folders. But you could create one for each then mesh them together with something like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotNetInstaller.aspx